# How do I edit the position of the image in a TableView cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I am trying to change the position of the images in my UITableViewController cells.  Here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIImageView *cellImage = cell.imageView;
    CGRect frame = cellImage.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 4;
    frame.origin.y = 2;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
}
```

So far the only thing that is working is the background color.  Any suggestions?
Here is a screenshot of what I have now:

[image]

Right now the images are centered but I was hoping to move them a little bit closer to the top-left of the cell.

Comment: You didn't update the frame on the cellImage. `CGRect`s are structs, not pointers, so assigning makes a copy, and your changes only affect the copy, not the original.

Comment: Set the frame again, once modified!

Comment: Are you trying to change frame of default `imageView` of `cell` ??? is this possible ?

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm trying to do. It may not be possible.

Comment: Would be better if you will add your own `UIImageView` on `cell.contentView` and then try to change its frame. And I read your comment you are using SDWebCache, So please explain more what you exactly want to do. May be we have better idea than this. :)

Comment: I was just hoping to move the images a little bit closer to the top left.  I uploaded a screen shot so you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your UI was created in IB and auto layout is turned on you need to update the constraints on the image view and then you don't even have to worry about changing the frame as auto layout will force the change itself. 
This guide is technically for OS X but most of it is the same: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853
There is also a WWDC video from 2012 that gives an overview if you are unfamiliar with auto layout all together.

Comment: The other option is to write your own custom UITableViewCell subclass that has the image view just where you want it.

Answer (score 1):

you can add this code to layoutSubviews method of cell. Something like this

```
-(void)layoutSubviews 
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    UIImageView *cellImage = self.imageView;
    CGRect frame = cellImage.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 4;
    frame.origin.y = 2;
    self.imageView.frame = frame;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

}
```

And don't forget to actually change self.imageView.frame

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you have modified the frame and the background color but you forgot to set the cell's actual frame. You need to add this after you change the frame:

```
cellImage.frame = frame;
```

or

```
cell.imageView.frame = frame;
```

The reason it is not working in your implementation is you are taking the image view's frame and setting it into another property (`frame` in this case). You are then changing that properties origin, not the cell's origin.

The background color worked because you are making that call directly on the cell `cell.backgroundColor` (you are calling the cell's setter). So you need to do the same thing with the view's frame.

Comment: Hmmm.... still not working the cell's text and the image are both aligned to the middle of the  cell.  Is there some kind of default align method that I need to turn off as well?

Comment: @kyzer1978 haha sorry, I made a change to my answer. See if this works.

Comment: Nope, still no luck. I am using SDWebImage to load my images from the web.  I wonder if that's the problem.

Comment: That shouldn't matter since an imageView is independent of the image inside it. Are you using the default imageView on table cells or did you personally add it?

Comment: I'm using the default imageView.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the way to achieve the same in one liner:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [cell.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(2, 4, cell.imageView.frame.size.width, cell.imageView.frame.size.height)];
}
```